# jQuery UI sortable’s serialize method excludes one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI `sortable` for a list of elements on a page whose order I want to save in the database every time it’s changed.

However, I’m experiencing a weird bug (it seems to me like one): both the `serialize` and `toArray` methods always exclude one item from the produced serialised string (or array). That always is the item being currently dragged. Which means the order is never actually tracked properly.

Here’s an example of my javascript:

```
$('.setContent').sortable({change:

    function(event, ui) {

        // Serialise the new order
        var newOrder = $('.setContent').sortable('serialize');

        // Add the current set id and the action name
        newOrder += '&setId='+currentSet+'&action=usrStuff:changeCardsOrder';

        // Send the data to the server
        $.post('ajax.php', newOrder);

   }

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="setContent>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_5">
        <div class="hanzi">俄国</div>
        <div class="meaning">Russia</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_4">
        <div class="hanzi">韩国</div>
        <div class="meaning">Korea</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_6">
        <div class="hanzi">中国</div>
        <div class="meaning">China</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_12">
        <div class="hanzi">日本</div>
        <div class="meaning">Japan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_13">
        <div class="hanzi">德国</div>
        <div class="meaning">Germany</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_17">
        <div class="hanzi">巴西</div>
        <div class="meaning">Brasil</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_14">
        <div class="hanzi">法国</div>
        <div class="meaning">France</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_19">
        <div class="hanzi">美国</div>
        <div class="meaning">America</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardSmall" id="card_16">
        <div class="hanzi">英国</div>
        <div class="meaning">England</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, in this case, there are nine items in the list. But the `sortable` method will only return information about eight.

[image: Screenshot of the window and with the JS console open]

So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want the `update` event, not the `change` event.

`change` fires *during* sorting whenever the ordering of the items in the DOM changes, even if the user hasn't let go of the item they're moving. `update` fires *after* the user has changed the order of the sortable elements.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot, it was stupid of me to miss something like this.

Comment: Thanks for this I also assumed this was the correct event because  The docs state "This event is triggered during sorting, but only when the DOM position has changed." if the dom position has changed then I would have to assume the element being dragged must be a part of the sortable.